# Failing updates in WS2012R2 @(KB3126593,KB3126593,KB3071756)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I have a freshly installed, properly licensed Windowsed Server 2012R2 that has 3 failing updates:

- Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3126593)
- Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3087088)
- Security Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3071756)

I tried killing the windows update service and clearing the software distribution folder several times, restarting machine in between attempts, manual installation of each update with web download, installing only one update at a time, looking up each of the updates and their requirements, looking up the error that is thrown...

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` hangs at 20%.

It might be worth noting that it also has trouble downloading these updates for some time. I can literally see the folders for these updates flicker in the SoftwareDistribution/Downloads folder. This resolves itself after a cleanup of SoftwareDistribution folder and process restart and some hours...

Nothing helped and then I gave up hoping it would resolve itself.. Unfurtunately it hasn't. See image below.

Errors thrown are:

> Installation status: Failed
>
> Error details: Code 80073701

and

> Installation status: Failed
>
> Error details: Code 80073712

Any ideas or suggestions? Do you need any more info?

Thanks.

[image: failing updates]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem on one of my production servers and, finally, MS support helped me:
Go to the registry and export the following key :
export and delete the following registry value, and then re-attempt the update: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\
make sure you leave the Publishers key empty.

If you are using ARM VM, than you can easily restore it from backup, test there and, if all is OK - perform the same on production VM

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't try it since I ended up just reinstalling my server after weeks with no solution. It also turned out to be a (soon) faulty HDD so it might have cause some corruption as well.